# Can't connect my Microsoft access database file using php (Xampp)

Tags: php, database, xampp

I made a php webpage with login and password it used run on my previous system (xampp was ran database in that system) but after installed xampp in my system  I started  Apcahce and Mysql (running succesfully). The login page ran all fine but once i tried to login it s giving me this error

```
**could not find driver
 Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\FINALschool\GLOBAL1.php on line 12
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in  C:\xampp\htdocs\FINALschool\GLOBAL1.php on line**
```

The  on my link to db folder is

```
<?php   
$dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "\FINALSCHOOL\REG.MDB";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
try{
    $db = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$dbName;Uid=Admin");
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

?>

I have also checked my user name and password for the login with  my database and it is all the same so please help
Also my xampp is connected to it's default port

Comment: DO you have the ODBC drivers in your XAMPP ? You may need to activate them (and uncomment in your PHP.ini)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just point to the .mdb file as a data source, you have to set up a MSAccess ODBC source:

Start at `Start > Settings > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Data Sources (ODBC)`

Then for your `$dbName` you use the DSN you chose as the name of source (e.g. "IguanaTestData" below).

[image: Setting up an ODBC Source]

[Reference](http://www.interfaceware.com/manual/setting_up_odbc_datasource.html)